# Oracle Merge Partition (based on partition values)

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

I would like to run a procedure that merges table partitions that match a certain criteria.

As example - table1  is range partitions by date and has 5 partitions.

Partitions = empire1, empire2, rebels1, rebels2, yoda1.

```
Table  DESC:
INVOICE_NO   NOT NULL NUMBER        
INVOICE_DATE NOT NULL DATE          
COMMENTS         VARCHAR2(500)
```

it is partitioned by INVOICE_DATE as follows

```
PARTITION REBELS1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')),
PARTITION REBELS2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')),
PARTITION EMPIRE1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016','DD-MON-YYYY')),
PARTITION EMPIRE2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017','DD-MON-YYYY')),
PARTITION YODA VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY')),
```

I need to grab all partitions named rebel% and yoda% and merge them into one new partition called 'jawa'.

In the end only 3 partitions would exist,  empire1, empire2 and jawa.

Comment: So, you want to merge based on partition **names**, not "values"??

Comment: Whether you can do that or not depends on the type of partition you have on the table. Range? (possible, but limited). List? (easiest) Hash? (not possible). You may want to start here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-54080399-6E59-4706-80C8-690159B20790.htm

Comment: Clarification - All partitions contain same data types, however they are range partitions by date. - (adding this to original post)

Comment: I did have a look at the link -- https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-54080399-6E59-4706-80C8-690159B20790.htm    The procedure would need to run and add names based on a "like" match. So in future it could be rebels1 2 3 4 5 ect and I need to get all of those (rebels%).  The link did not show an example other than exact names..

Comment: You can't do that in plain SQL (including ALTER TABLE statements). Partition names must be fully expanded when the statement is sent to the database server. You may be thinking like `cat rebels*` in UNIX - there you have the shell expand the wildcard expression for you, the command `CAT` does not see `rebels*`, it sees the fully expanded list of file names. SQL requires the fully expanded list. If you must do something with `rebels%` you will need to write a small piece of PL/SQL code and then execute the resulting (dynamic) SQL statement.

Comment: "All partitions contain same data types" what does this mean? they are partitions of the same table therefore they have the same column with the same data type.

Comment: the content of a partition is determined by the partition criteria not by its name. so tell us the partition criterias.

Comment: The partitions are Range by " INVOICE_DATE"

Comment: Partition = Range by date.

Comment: I have added clarification to Original post.

Comment: From the link to the documentation: "When merging multiple range partitions, the partitions must be adjacent", but the yoda partition is not adjacent to a rebels partition. So you cannot merg the partitions this way

Comment: If you not  a  @username in your comment, no one will be notified about your comment.